# papyrus class diagram: using entity-type attribute when associating 2 classes

Tags: associations, class-diagram, papyrus

i am using Papyrus with Eclipse Kepler SR2, trying to make a class-diagram.
I have 2 classes: Product and Order and an association between them. Do i have to add an attribute of type Product in the Order class (i've seen that that's possible) or is the association enough, should i succeed in generating java code from this diagram (which i saw is rather complicated).

I have to mention that I am new to the whole modeling thing and I know that the question may seem idiotic but i really couldn't find an answer anywhere (i've tried google, didn't help) and I would like my diagram to be correct.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

When adding the association between Product and Order, depending on the type of association, the editor will add an attribute automatically to both entities. So no need to manually add them.